Why Is Android Studio Emulator Stuck On Booting Android Logo?
The emulator is stuck booting. It's been on the same screen all day even though I tried multiple times. I tried wiping the data, tried changing the ram size to 512, even tried three or four different avds. I deleted them because they were useless. Nothing is working. I looked for a solution everywhere. Sadly, none has works for me so far. Running from the command line, there are no errors. Help me out please.


Try using any of the latest models of AVD. I am using the below for now and it's perfectly working and much faster.

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling the emulator from SDK Tools in Settings.
Otherwise, check if you have hardware acceleration. More information on https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration
